# Can't figure out foreign key constraint fail

Tags: mysql

I'm developing an app and use MySQL as the backend. Overall it's working out great. However, I have a foreign key constraint failure that keeps popping up on the same insertions and I can't figure out the issue. Likely, it's obvious but.. I suspect I've stared and poked and prodded too long, so would love another pair of eyes.

First, here is the error that MySQL is throwing:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rtm`.`rtm_psa_subissue`, CONSTRAINT `rtm_psa_subissue_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`psa_parent_id`) REFERENCES `rtm_psa_issue` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT)
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `rtm_psa_subissue` (`tenant_id`, `psa_id`, `name`, `is_active`, `psa_parent_id`, `oplock`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `uuid`) VALUES (5, 592, 'Complaint/Operations', FALSE, 50, FALSE, NOW(), NOW(), NULL, NULL, '15c8c746f2cd11eb9f221204fb92bd6d')
```

Note that my code is able to insert the bulk of entries in rtm_psa_subissue, but then begins throwing exceptions at the same spot every time.

Now let's show data in rtm_psa_issue where 48 >= rtm_psa_issue.psa_id <= 52 based on the statement above just to show the before/after psa_id values:

```
mysql> select id,name,psa_id from rtm_psa_issue where psa_id > 48 and psa_id < 52;
+----+-----------------------+--------+
| id | name                  | psa_id |
+----+-----------------------+--------+
| 27 | 13 Office Management  |     49 |
| 28 | 10 Account Management |     50 |
| 29 | 21 TMS                |     51 |
+----+-----------------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Okay, great, there is in fact a row for rtm_psa_issue.psa_id = 50 in the foreign table.

Let's see if the row rtm_psa_subissue.psa_id = 592 exist:

```
mysql> select id,name,psa_id,psa_parent_id from rtm_psa_subissue where psa_id > 590 and psa_id < 594;
+-----+------------+--------+---------------+
| id  | name       | psa_id | psa_parent_id |
+-----+------------+--------+---------------+
| 212 | 10 IT Lead |    591 |            17 |
+-----+------------+--------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

No, doesn't exist yet.

So what is going on?

I don't know how to show foreign keys directly via the mysql client, but here is the PHP code to create them:

rtm_psa_issue

```
$this->addForeignKey(
    'rtm_psa_issue_ibfk_1',
    '{{%psa_issue}}',
    ['tenant_id'],
    '{{%user}}',
    ['id'],
    'RESTRICT',         // this is for ON DELETE
    'NO ACTION'         // this is for ON UPDATE
);
```

rtm_psa_subissue

```
$this->addForeignKey(
    'rtm_psa_subissue_ibfk_1',
    '{{%psa_subissue}}',
    ['tenant_id'],
    '{{%user}}',
    ['id'],
    'RESTRICT',         // this is for ON DELETE
    'NO ACTION'         // this is for ON UPDATE
);
$this->addForeignKey(
    'rtm_psa_subissue_ibfk_2',
    '{{%psa_subissue}}',
    ['psa_parent_id'],
    '{{%psa_issue}}',
    ['id'],
    'RESTRICT',         // this is for ON DELETE
    'NO ACTION'         // this is for ON UPDATE
);
```

Comment: `psa_parrent_id` references the `id` column, not the `psa_id` column: "FOREIGN KEY (`psa_parent_id`) REFERENCES `rtm_psa_issue` (`id`)"

Answer (score 1):

`psa_parrent_id` references the `id` column, not the `psa_id` column

```
FOREIGN KEY (`psa_parent_id`) REFERENCES `rtm_psa_issue` (`id`)
```

Comment: OH WOW. :(

Now that's a stupid bug. Great catch, thank you!